# Plugin to turn off RTE on select page

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Anyone know of the plugin that lets you selectively turn off the RTE, on a per-page or posts basis?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I don't know of a plugin ... but it's easy enough to do this with a filter in your `functions.php` file (or in a custom plugin.

This code, for example, turns off the rich text editor for everything with the post type "presentation":

```
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit', 'disable_for_cpt' );
function disable_for_cpt( $allowed ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'presentation' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        $allowed = false;
    }
    return $allowed;
}
```

You could do whatever checks you need in this filter.  Check if the post/page has a certain ID or a certain slug.  Or even check if it's in a specific category:

```
global $post;
if ( in_category( 'no_rte', $post ) ) {
    // ...
```

Really, the sky's the limit.